# Partial string match two columns R

Tags: regex, r

I have been trying to partially match two column contents based on a list of regular expressions common to both columns:

```
dats<-data.frame(ID=c(1:3),species=c("dog","cat","rabbit"),
species.descriptor=c("all animal dog","all animal cat","rabbit exotic"),product=c(1,2,3),
product.authorise=c("all animal dog cat rabbit","cat horse pig","dog cat"))
```

with the aim of achieving this:

```
goal<-data.frame(ID=c(1:3),species=c("dog","cat","rabbit"),
            species.descriptor=c("all animal dog","all animal cat","rabbit exotic"),
            product=c(1,2,3),product.authorise=c("all animal dog cat rabbit","cat horse pig",
            "dog cat"), authorised=c("TRUE","TRUE","FALSE"))
```

So to explain further, if 'dog' appears at any point in both columns, then this would be considered 'TRUE' in $match - and this would apply for any individual species descriptor.If no matches are found, then a return of either FALSE or an na would be fine.

So far I have gotten to this point:

```
library(stringr)
patts<-c("dog","cat","all animal")
reg.patts<-paste(patts,collapse="|")
dats$matched<-ifelse((str_extract(dats$species.descriptor,reg.patts) == str_extract(dats$product.authorise,reg.patts)),"TRUE","FALSE")
dats
  ID species species.descriptor product         product.authorise matched
   1     dog     all animal dog       1 all animal dog cat rabbit    TRUE
   2     cat     all animal cat       2             cat horse pig   FALSE
   3  rabbit      rabbit exotic       3                   dog cat    <NA>
```

As you can see, this correctly identifies the first and last rows as 'all animal' appears first in both strings, and there is no match at all in the last. However, it seems to struggle (as in the second row) when the reg exp doesn't appear first in the string. I have tried str_extract_all, but have only resulted in error messages so far. I was wondering if anyone can help, please?

Comment: Apologies knew I forgot something! library(stringr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `dplyr` for piping.  The core component is using `grepl` for logical string matching of `species` in both `species.descriptor` and `product.authorised`.

```
library(dplyr)
dats %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(authorised = 
           grepl(species, species.descriptor) & 
           grepl(species, product.authorise)
       )

Source: local data frame [3 x 6]
Groups: <by row>

     ID species species.descriptor product         product.authorise authorised
  (int)  (fctr)             (fctr)   (dbl)                    (fctr)      (lgl)
1     1     dog     all animal dog       1 all animal dog cat rabbit       TRUE
2     2     cat     all animal cat       2             cat horse pig       TRUE
3     3  rabbit      rabbit exotic       3                   dog cat      FALSE
```

If you really like `stringr` you can use the `str_detect` function for more user friendly syntax.

```
library(stringr)
dats %>%
mutate(authorised = 
           str_detect(species.descriptor, species) & 
           str_detect(product.authorise, species)
       )
```

And if you don't like `dplyr` you can add the column directly

```
dats$authorised <- 
    with(dats, 
         str_detect(species.descriptor, species) & 
             str_detect(product.authorise, species)
         )
```

Comment: dplyr is not at all necessary here, op wasnt using it, why are you introducing a dependency

Comment: Thanks for your input, both! All versions you've provided work fine - only comment is needed to convert dats$species to a character before str_detect versions worked. Generally prefer base R versions for speed, but in this case str_detect was very quick and easier syntax.