# Regex double column matching R

Tags: regex, r, if-statement, stringr

This is a follow on from a question I asked yesterday:
[Partial string match two columns R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951410/partial-string-match-two-columns-r)

The answer provided to this was great; however, I found that many species were not directly referred too i.e. a tortoise was never described directly in dats$product.authorise, but 'exotic' was an acceptable match.

```
dats<-data.frame(ID=c(1:4),species=c("dog","cat","rabbit","tortoise"),
            species.descriptor=c("all animal dog","all animal cat","rabbit exotic","tortoise exotic"),
            product=c(1,2,3,4),product.authorise=c("all animal dog cat rabbit","cat horse pig",
            "dog cat","exotic"))
dats
  ID  species species.descriptor product         product.authorise
   1      dog     all animal dog       1 all animal dog cat rabbit
   2      cat     all animal cat       2             cat horse pig
   3   rabbit      rabbit exotic       3                   dog cat
   4 tortoise    tortoise exotic       4                    exotic
```

I have come up with a solution that works based on binding $species.descriptor and $product.authorise together and then designating the row as 'TRUE' if a particular reg exp appears two or more times in the field like so:

```
library(stringr)
dats$bound<-paste(dats$product.authorise, dats$species.descriptor)

species_descriptor<-c("all animal","dog","cat","rabbit","exotic","horse","pig","tortoise")
species_descriptor<-setNames(nm=species_descriptor)
result<-ifelse(sapply(species_descriptor, str_count, string=dats$bound)>=2,"TRUE","FALSE")
result<-as.data.frame(result)

result$AuthorisedCount<-apply(result[,1:ncol(result)],MARGIN=1,function(x){sum(x=="TRUE",na.rm=T)})
result$SpeciesAuthorised<-ifelse(result$AuthorisedCount>=1,"TRUE","FALSE")

dats<-cbind(dats, result$SpeciesAuthorised)
names(dats)[7]<-"SpeciesAuthorised" 
dats$bound<-NULL

dats
  ID  species species.descriptor product         product.authorise SpeciesAuthorised
   1      dog     all animal dog       1 all animal dog cat rabbit              TRUE
   2      cat     all animal cat       2             cat horse pig              TRUE
   3   rabbit      rabbit exotic       3                   dog cat             FALSE
   4 tortoise    tortoise exotic       4                    exotic              TRUE
```

This is fine and on the much larger dataset works quickly; however, I am aware that there is probably a much more elegant way of doing things. I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Using the `sapply` function call and the `bound` variable to produce the same result:

```
bound<-paste(dats$product.authorise, dats$species.descriptor)
dats$SpeciesAuthorised <- as.logical(rowSums(sapply(species_descriptor, str_count, string=bound)>=2))
# ID  species species.descriptor product         product.authorise SpeciesAuthorised
# 1  1      dog     all animal dog       1 all animal dog cat rabbit              TRUE
# 2  2      cat     all animal cat       2             cat horse pig              TRUE
# 3  3   rabbit      rabbit exotic       3                   dog cat             FALSE
# 4  4 tortoise    tortoise exotic       4                    exotic              TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending on the post you mentioned would this work?

```
dats$SpeciesAuthorised <-  with(dats, 
                                str_detect(species.descriptor, species) & 
                                  (str_detect(product.authorise, species) | str_detect(species.descriptor,product.authorise))
)
```

I just added an OR operator to the function to detect for patterns in product.authorise within species.descriptor.

```
dats
  ID  species species.descriptor product         product.authorise SpeciesAuthorised
1  1      dog     all animal dog       1 all animal dog cat rabbit              TRUE
2  2      cat     all animal cat       2             cat horse pig              TRUE
3  3   rabbit      rabbit exotic       3                   dog cat             FALSE
4  4 tortoise    tortoise exotic       4                    exotic              TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the code using the function `any`:

```
bound  <- paste(dats$product.authorise, dats$species.descriptor)
result <- ifelse(sapply(species_descriptor, str_count, string=bound)>=2, TRUE, FALSE)

dats$SpeciesAuthorised <- apply(result, 1, any)
```

And no need to set the results to `"TRUE"` or `"FALSE"` as characters, use logicals.

Also, if you want to make the code more clean and readable, you can define your own functions:

```
isSpeciesAuthorised = function(data, species_descriptor) {
  bound  <- paste(data$product.authorise, data$species.descriptor)
  result <- ifelse(sapply(species_descriptor, str_count, string=bound)>=2, TRUE, FALSE)

  return(apply(result, 1, any)) 
}
```

And then use them:

```
dats$SpeciesAuthorised <- isSpeciesAuthorised(data=dats, species_descriptor)
```